# What's wrong with this VB.NET Substring call?

Tags: vb.net

```
 dim dataType as String
  toolTip="Marks And Number[String]"
```

I want to get the [String] alone.

```
  dataType = toolTipText.Substring(toolTipText.IndexOf("[") + 1, toolTipText.IndexOf("]") - 1)
```

it shows an error. Regarding the length of the string.

What's wrong with my code.I dont know ,
Some times I have these type of problems . Standing with simple loops or conditions .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter is length, not ending index. You need to subtract your starting index from it.

Answer (score 2):

Not that it's great code but

```
dataType = toolTip.Substring(toolTip.IndexOf("[") + 1, toolTip.Length - toolTip.IndexOf("[") - 2)
```

would sort you out.

The second parameter is the length of the substring - not the end index.

Might be better to take a look at regex.